# Tangent planes to a Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading a section on Tangent spaces on Submanifolds from a book on Differential geometry by Wolfgang Kuhnell.

Since I don't see why it is any different to consider Tangent bundles on manifolds, I will resort to replacing "submanifold" with "manifold" $M$.

In the book Tangent bundles are defined as the space,

$$
T\mathbb{R}^n := \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n
$$

which I infer as the set of all ordered pairs of points with all possible tangent vectors to the manifold at that point.

Then the Tangent space at some $p \in M$ is defined as the subset of the Tangent bundle

$$
T_p\mathbb{R}^n := \{p\} \times \mathbb{R}^n
$$

which is a generalized case of a tangent plane to a parameterized surface $f$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which contains the vectors indicating all possible directions we can move on $M$ at $p$

However a fact in the section, that goes by,

$$
\forall x \neq y \in \mathbb{R}^n : T_x\mathbb{R}^n \cap T_y\mathbb{R}^n = \phi 
$$

is stated as something to be "by definition" and I fail to understand why this fact is trivial. But as a counter example in $\mathbb{R}^3$ we can always consider two distinct points on, say, a sphere that intersect to give a line so why is it that, in general, the tangent planes at distinct points on manifolds are disjoint?

Answer (score 1):

A general manifold should not be thought as a subset of some $\mathbb{R}^N$ for some large $N$ (embedded manifold), although this is actually possible for smooth ones. Each tangent space is attached to its base point, but they are otherwise disjoint. For example, in Mechanics the configuration manifold has tangent vectors defining different virtual displacements from the given point. Identifying virtual displacements from two different initial states does not make sense.